# Object tree traversal - afl for app memory leak detection

Tags: actionscript-3, garbage-collection, ecmascript-5

I am trying to traverse object tree in AFL (adobe flash lite) engine, to check if there are memory leaks in an event driven application (AS3). The idea is to get object tree dump before and after an event processing and check the object tree dump difference for memory leaks.

I believe MMgc is the GC for AFL, I am unable to get a dump of object tree, can anyone help me to point out where in code I can get the alive object info in [tamarin](http://hg.mozilla.org/tamarin-central).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried tho profile with [FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/Intro_To_Profiling_Applications), [FlashBuilder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7e46.html) or [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page)? Or [MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/)?

Comment: No I cant use any of them, I am trying to profile an app that will run on embedded platform. I will have to get all the info from flash lite engine.